# Interacting with a Custom Token Contract

Tags: web3js, truffle, tokens, contract-deployment, truffle-test

I seem to be having problems interacting with a custom token contract.  I am using truffle and ganache for my testing.  I am trying to interact with the custom token contract so MyContract can transfer tokens to an address on behalf of the custom token contract.  I do have the ABI as well.

custom token contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;
import "./MintableToken.sol";
contract CustomToken is MintableToken {
  // Coin Properties
  string public name = "Custom Token";
  string public symbol = "Cust";
  uint256 public decimals = 18;
  function transfer(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool) {
    return super.transfer(_to, _value);
  }
}
```

MyContract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

import "./CustomToken.sol";

contract MyContract is CustomToken{

    function transferCustom(address _to, uint _value) public returns (bool) {
        require(_to != address(0));


        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        Transfer(msg.sender,_to,_value);

        return true;
    }
}
```

truffle test:

```
const accountfirst  = web3.eth.accounts[1];
const amount = 100;

let token = await CustomToken.deployed();
let myContract = await MyContract.deployed();

var ctoken = CustomToken.at(token.address);
ctoken.approve(myContract.address, amount);
let tx = await myContract.transferCustom(accountfirst, amount);
```

When i run this test i get transaction reverted. Any ideas? thank you in advance!

Comment: i've narrowed down the error and it seems to come from this line:

let tx = await myContract.transferCustom(accountfirst, amount);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the issue is sending a null address to the contract and then `require(_to != address(0));`. The contract function requirement is good, but the sending null is a client-side problem.

I don't think this (below) works synchronously, so accountfirst is null when the function is invoked, so the transaction reverts.

```
const accountfirst  = web3.eth.accounts[1];
```

Try fetching the account asynchronously.

```
web3.eth.getAccounts()
.then(function(response) {
   account = response[0]);
   // carry on
}
```

or

```
web3.eth.getAccounts(function(err,response) { 
  account = response[0];
  // carry on
}
```

Hope it helps.